# pandas: cannot do positional indexing on DatetimeIndex with these indexers [2016-08-01 00:00:00] of Timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I a newbie using pandas, I am trying to access my (date indexed) dataframe `df` using code similar to this:

```
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    if idx < startrow:
        continue

    col1_data = df.iloc[idx]['col1']
```

I get the following error:

```
cannot do positional indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex'> with these indexers [2016-08-01 00:00:00] of <class 'pandas._libs.tslib.Timestamp'>
```

How do I fix this ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `iloc` needs to be `loc`, as the former is [*integer-location based indexing*](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html); To select rows by labels (or the actual index as is `idx`) you need [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
col1_data = df.loc[idx]['col1']
```